# Special foreign characters in vue js file

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having an issue with displaying foreign characters.

In my Laravel blade file, it shows correctly but in my vue file it doesn't. I tried almost all possible `utf-8` solution like this

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

[image]

They are same word, one in blade file and one in vue file. Vue file's word is not displaying properly.

Many thanks.

Comment: <meta charset=utf-8">

Comment: I tried it too but no result

Comment: they are same font?

Comment: yes they are same in same project

Comment: Ok. Right click on page, inspect element and check in browser's developer tools if this tag is generated in right place. So, in header element.

Comment: didn't get you.

Comment: show your code so that we can see the problem

Comment: HI, fixed it using editor encoding.